# Regex Match First Character of Column

Tags: regex, linux, awk, grep

I currently have a file called computers.txt

> ST 314, Fox, PC, Unix
>   ST 13, Newman, Mac
>   ST 212, Frank, Linux, PC
>   BP 311, Jones, PC
>   ST 404, Walden, PC, Linux
>   ST 303, Noblitt, PC
>   ST 102, Christensen, Mac
>   ST 301, Ward, PC
>   SB 444, Smith, Mac
>   ST 202, Kirby, Mac, PC
>   ST 361, Lab, Linux
>   ST 333, Hu, Unix, PC

I need show the line using regex if the members name begins with the letter F, G, H, I, J or K. Any help?

Comment: Regex may be the wrong tool for this job. Why not `awk split` on the comma and then just grab the first character of the second token?

Answer (score 1):

With **grep**:

```
grep '^[^,]*, *[FGHIJK]' file
```

The output:

```
ST 314, Fox, PC, Unix
ST 212, Frank, Linux, PC
BP 311, Jones, PC
ST 202, Kirby, Mac, PC
ST 333, Hu, Unix, PC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F', *' '$2 ~ /^[FGHIJK]/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat jake
ST 314, Fox, PC, Unix
ST 13, Newman, Mac
ST 212, Frank, Linux, PC
BP 311, Jones, PC
ST 404, Walden, PC, Linux
ST 303, Noblitt, PC
ST 102, Christensen, Mac
ST 301, Ward, PC
SB 444, Smith, Mac
ST 202, Kirby, Mac, PC
ST 361, Lab, Linux
ST 333, Hu, Unix, PC
```

And then

```
awk -F, '$2~/^[FGHIJK]/' jake
ST 314, Fox, PC, Unix
ST 212, Frank, Linux, PC
BP 311, Jones, PC
ST 202, Kirby, Mac, PC
ST 333, Hu, Unix, PC
```

Comment: That would match anywhere in the field, not just at the start. Consider a name like `MacIntyre`. Once you fix that you'll have [the same answer as I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46571890/1745001).

Comment: True that. Thanks Ed